# logic app arm deployment unsaved changes warning

Tags: azure-logic-apps, savechanges, azure-rm-template

I am not sure if anyone faced this issue. I created a logic app in portal. Then I used the  [Logic app template creator utility](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator) to extract the template and parameter files. After that I deployed the template using powershell. Now when I go into the designer and even move the mouse a bit the logic app menu changes to highlight "save" as if I have done some changes. After that if I try to close the designer it prompts that unsaved changes would be lost. However I didn't do any changes. I am not sure why this is happening.  The logic app I used is HTTP triggered and has blob and sql db connectors. This is happening with all the logic apps I deployed using the arm template created using the utility. Anyone faced this symptom - if so please help.

Comment: I faced this problem and just ignored it. I haven't seen any side effect. But I guess it is a bug you can report it to the microsoft team

Comment: @Thomas, I see, in my case it was some missing artifacts to be used by the logic app. Now the problem is no longer there once the artifacts were deployed.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems this happens if some of the connectors have got missing parameters in the deployment. In my case I had deployed logic app but had missed out creating some blob containers and stored procs that it was supposed to use. Once I had these containers and stored procs deployed, then editing and closing the logic app no longer showed the unsaved change message.